# How many logic gates are realistically feasible?

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, boolean-algebra

I'm actually more of a software developer and don't really know much about electrical engineering. But I do have a basic understanding of Boolean diagrams. So I had an idea for a Boolean circuit, the only gates I need are AND and OR gates. But to make my circuit useful, it needs about 2.5 million of those gates. How realistic is that something like this works? Can estimate how big or expensive such a circuit would have to be.

Like I said, I don't know much about electrical engineering. But as far as I know, AND and OR gates made up of only a few transistors. When I google for size of transistors, it tells me that they are about 5 nanometers in size. That has given me hope that somehow that my idea is still realizable...

Comment: How many inputs to your gates ? Don't you need inverters as well ? Do everything to be combinatorial or can it be iterative or pipelined?

Comment: Take a look at PLDs (programmable logic devices). They have a bunch of various kinds of gates on the device. You then set up the connections between the gates by programming the device. Really handy for trying something out because if you have an error, you can reprogram the device with a new layout and keep doing that until you get it working.

Comment: Define feasible. What sort of power budget are you expecting, and what kind of propagation delays can you tolerate? Consider that some current CPUs have transistor counts into the billions (the 32-core AMD Epyc processor has 19.2 billion transistors per Wikipedia...)

Comment: It is extraordinarily unlikely that a *purely combinatorial* circuit remotely that size is going to be practical or at least not the best way of solving a problem.  Real solutions alternate combinatorial stages with pipeline registers.  You should probably spend some time studying logic design, targeting a whiteboard, simulator, and then FPGA in that order to get an idea of what is actually built. Things with more gates than your plan are of course routine, but in say the computer you are typing on, they are use with more strategy and wise organization.

Comment: Are there a lot of these gates in series - outputs of one connecting to an input on the next stage? If so you'll have to look at the propagation delays that accumulate as the signal ripples through them all.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the premise of *software* is to keep a smaller number of gates busier by having them do different things in sequence.  Typically outside of school you only build custom logic for a problem if it has to be done with blinding speed or incessant repetition, and even then you'll often cycle the same engine over a range of data in sequence, treating parts of the problem in serial fashion and others in parallel.

Comment: @TEMLIB about 2000 inputs. With inverte you mean an NOT gate? No I don't need NOT gates. I do not exactly know what you mean by pipelined, but yes my circuit should solve a combinatorial  problem

Comment: @zeta-band ok i will take a look at it. But a software developer it is already clear to me that you i can simulate boolean circuits. But the idea was that i can do it much faster if it happens in a real circuit. That's correct, isn't it?

Comment: @AdamLawrence 
ok now I already feel a bit stupid because i don't know what power budget  and propagation delays mean. I will inform myself about it. the one thing with the billion transistors was also something I had heard somewhere in the past and so I thought it would certainly be doable

Comment: Your 2000 inputs would have to be changing tens of *millions* of times per second to rule out a partially serialized approach as most easy and economical.  And if that were the case, you'd need a fair amount of experience just to viably *present* them to the circuit.

Comment: @manzet Yes, the hardware will be faster. The PLD isn't a simulation, but is hardware where the interconnections can be reconfigured. They can be used to do some things amazingly fast.

Comment: Y'oure not telling us about what this circuit is supposed to achieve, but why does it have to be hardwired? 2000 inputs for a combinatorial-only circuit seems very strange. Are you sure it isn't something that could be done by a regular CPU? That would be much cheaper.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to give some info on the end goal.  A circuit board with 2000 signals is... not trivial.

Comment: @dim i am sure that it is something that can be done by a cpu because i have already simulated it on a higher level (python). But what the whole thing is based on is the idea that it should actually go much faster if you have an actual circuit like if you simulate it.

Comment: @Selvek i would really like to discuss my whole idea, also the reason why i would need about 2000 inputs. Unfortunately this is nothing I can't do in a forum ....

Comment: @manzet At least clarify what you mean by 2000 inputs.  Are they physical wires, or do they originate from software somewhere?

Comment: @manzet You can't expect people to give you sensible answers without more information. How fast does it need to be? Maybe the inputs be somewhat preprocessed in hardware by multiple cheap FPGAs/CPLDs, and then mixed together by some other FPGAs/CPLDs, or a CPU, in a hierarchical way? But we can't guess what the architecture should be without more information. We can only make random suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck. Devices already exists that can implement this logic circuit for you. They're called [FPGAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array).

They consist of millions of logic blocks which can be individually programmed, as well as interconnects which can *also* be reprogrammed.

It's hard to say what the price would be. If the speed doesn't have to be crazy you might be able to use multiple cheaper devices. But it looks like if you wanted to do this whole thing on one chip, you could. If you can drop like 20k on one chip..

No matter what you do, the resulting device could be pretty small.

Comment: Unless you can demonstrate an available FPGA with 2000 inputs (and an unknown number of outputs, which might be as small as one), he's not in luck. Xilinx, for instance, doesn't have a part with I/O count more than 1200.

Comment: ...which means you need to split the design.  Which means identifying intermediate results.  Which is on the way the way towards collapsing it into an actually reasonable and appropriate solution to the problem, which if thought through is overwhelming likely to yield a much smaller, better cheaper solution.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, inputs can be serialized, Xilinx, for example, has dedicated  SERDES blocks for this, from 6 Gbps to 30+ Gbps. You can move a lot of parallel bits nearly at once...

Comment: @Ale..chenski - Yes, but that will take extra chips to serialize the 2000 lines the OP mentions. He specifically asked for a one-chip solution.